# Why Python believe we are living in 20th century?

Tags: python

```
timestamp = time.time()
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
dt = dt.strftime("%C%Y%m%d%H%M.%S")
dt
```

Why this return 20202312240520.14?

What does the first 20 mean in the return?

Body must be at least 220, so I type this sentence.

Comment: There is no mistake or problem or anything strange here, just a failure to read the documentation https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/manpages-dev/strftime.3.en.html as referred to by https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes - what did you expect `%C` to mean? Or did you just not know and decide to ask SO instead of looking at the doco?

Comment: The %C format specifier will produce ambiguous values in the context of trying to determine the century. Both years 2000, and 2001 would generate 20 but the former is in the 20th century whereas the latter is in the 21st century

Answer (score 2):

Where did you come across `%C` without an accompanying description of what it meant? It’s implementation-defined to begin with (not on the [standard list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)), but my `man strftime` explains pretty clearly:

```
     %C    is replaced by (year / 100) as decimal number; single digits are
           preceded by a zero.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%C` directive is used to extract the century part from the current date. As of the current year 2023, the `%C` will extract the first two digits from the current year which are `20`(23), so `%C` is printing 20 only.

Your code formats the date and time using `%C%Y%m%d%H%M.%S`. Let's break it down:

```
%C: Century part (20 for the 21st century)
%Y: Year (2023)
%m: Month (12)
%d: Day (24)
%H: Hour (05)
%M: Minute (20)
%S: Second (.14)
```

Combining these, you get `20202312240520.14` as the final output.

If you wanted to print 21st as century, then you need to do it manually as:

```
timestamp = time.time()
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
current_century = str(int(dt.strftime("%C")) + 1) + 'st Century'
date_time = dt.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M.%S")
>>> current_century
    21st Century
>>> date_time
    202312240520.14
```